# Using std::vector<boost::function> with boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

While trying to get comfortable with `boost`, stumbled into problem with using `boost::function` along with `std::vector`. I'm trying to do a simple thing: have a list of functions with similair signatures and then use all that functions with `std::for_each` on sample data. Here is the code:

```
typedef boost::function<int (const char*)> text_processor;
typedef std::vector<text_processor> text_processors;
text_processors processors;
processors.push_back(std::atoi);
processors.push_back(std::strlen);

const char data[] = "123";

std::for_each(processors.begin(), processors.end(),
    std::cout << boost::bind(&text_processors::value_type::operator(), _1, data) 
              << "\n"
);
```

So, with `for_each` I'm trying to write to standard output the result of applying every function to sample data. But it won't compile like this (some long message about missing operator `<<` for `bind` result).

If I remove stream operators then I'll have compilable, but useless code. The trick is that I want to do function applying and text output in single `for_each`. What am I missing? Thought it should be easy with lambdas or smth like that, but can't figure out the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to create a functor in place in a way that is not allowed (you cannot just throw code at the third argument of `for_each`, you need to pass *a functor*).

Without lambda support in the compiler you can use `std::transform` rather than `std::for_each` (not tested... but this should work):

```
std::transform( processors.begin(), processors.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ),
                bind( &text_processors::value_type::operator(), _1, data ) );
```

If your compiler supports lambdas you can do with it:

```
const char data[] = "123";
std::for_each(processors.begin(), processors.end(),
    [&data]( text_processors const & ) { 
        std::cout << boost::bind(&text_processors::value_type::operator(), _1, data) 
              << "\n"
    }
);
```

But then you can avoid the `bind` altogether:

```
std::for_each( processors.begin(), processors.end(),
               [&data]( text_processors::value_type & op ) {
                   std::cout << op( data ) << "\n";
               }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Solution with `std::transform` seems to pull the trick. I was trying to wrap my head around of couple of facts: `std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << "\n"` is a functor and `boost::bind(...)` is a functor. But I still see no way to combine them in single functor to pass it to `std::for_each`.

Comment: I have not used the boost lambda library, and it's been long since I read the docs, but IIRC there is a `boost::lambda::bind` that might be in the lines of what you need. Again, no real experience, your mileage might vary.